# How to get magento admin token with restsharp

Tags: c#, api, magento, magento2, restsharp

I'm pretty new to rest API and restsharp so I need some help. I need to get a magento version 2.2.3 admin token but I keep getting a bad request. I've followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sdGuC7IUAI&t=343s. But I'm ending up with a bad request. When I check the statuscode using a the breakpoints from the tutorial I get: NotFound.

My main goal is to get the categories I have in Magento. But to get that I need an admin token. I already have a bearer acces code etc.

I would really appreciate your help.

my code so far:
magento.cs:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using RestSharp;  
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MagentoTest
{
    public class magento
    {
        private RestClient Client { get; set; }
        private string Token { get; set; }

        public magento(string magentoUrl)
        {
            Client = new RestClient(magentoUrl);
        }

        public magento(string magentoUrl,string token)
        {
            Client = new RestClient(magentoUrl);
            Token = token;
        }

        public string GetAdminToken(string userName, string passWord)
        {
            var request = CreateRequest("/rest/V1/integration/admin/token", Method.POST);
            var user = new Credentials();
            user.username = userName;
            user.password = passWord;

            string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented);

            request.AddParameter("aplication/json", Json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response = Client.Execute(request);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return response.Content;
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

        private RestRequest CreateRequest(string endPoint, Method method)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(endPoint, method);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

Credentials:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MagentoTest
{
    public class Credentials
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(Client)
Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MagentoTest;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetToken("blabla", "blabla");
        }

        static void GetToken(string userName, string passWord)
        {
            var m2 = new magento("http://beta.topprice24.com");
            string token = m2.GetAdminToken(userName, passWord);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have created so far?

Comment: I've edited the question because I couldn't put the code in a comment. And instead of the real username and password i've put blabla ofcourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks, relative URL needs to be changed as "/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token" 
(https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/order-tutorial/order-admin-token.html).

I have simplified the above code and you can easily get the token.

Keep your Credentials class as it is and change your main program as below

**Modified Code:(Program.cs)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {       
            //Base URL needs to be Specified
            String host = "http://beta.topprice24.com";
            //Relative URL needs to be Specified
            String endpoint = "/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token";

            RestClient _restClient = new RestClient(host);
            var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.POST);

            //Initialize Credentials Property
            var userRequest = new Credentials{username="blabla",password="blabla"};
            var inputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRequest);

            //Request Header
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            //Request Body
            request.AddParameter("application/json", inputJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response = _restClient.Execute(request);

            var token=response.Content;         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check your input JSON ?

Comment: I have modified your main Program and updated code will work fine. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: As per the doc, (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/order-tutorial/order-admin-token.html), you can get the Admin Token by passing the admin username and password. Please recheck with the above updated code

Comment: I received the token. Thank you verry much!

Comment: Glad to know it helped:) Please accept the answer and give the upvote

Comment: I did give the upvote but because of my lack of rep it won't show it publicly -.-'

Comment: you need to have minimum 15 Reputation to do the upvote and no worries, you can give it later:)

Comment: @Subburaj If i try to get customer list using REST API i am getting error -> screenshot -> https://snag.gy/3PSxvm.jpg -> URL -> http://127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/customers. and if i try to get products its working -> screenshot -> https://snag.gy/sePpyw.jpg -> url http://127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/products, can i help regard customer API error?

Comment: @Rathinam: It looks , you are not having enough permission to access the customers endpoint and hence you are getting 403 error. Please add the Authorization header in your request and then check. If you are still face an error, then please raise it as separate question with your sample code. I will help you to solve the problem

Comment: @Subburaj My account not working properly, i cant able to post, in future i will post and let you know, can you help me now?

Comment: @Subburaj shall i proceed?

Comment: @Rathinam: Please get the customer token and then use it in your code as below `request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <customer token>");`